# Need help in coding image switcher navigation with small spheres changing on image change using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have 3 images which switches once at every 5 secs. They are arranged in a sequence on my index page. Below these images, I have set up 3 spheres in order having left & right arrows  before and after these spheres as shown below

< O O O >

I need to change one image at a time on every image change depicting one sphere selected.

< Ø O O >

Also on clicking one of the sphere should select the respective image. 
Kindly help me

Comment: What do you have so far? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

yes, what code are you trying now? The generally used thought behind these types of ui elements is that you:
1. on click, find the element with the 'current' class.
2. remove that class.
3. set the item that was clicked on, or in the case of arrows only the next or prev item by appending the class 'current'.

You can look into switching the src attr on click or just using a sprite and adjusting the background image from no cross bar to a cross bar etc.

That's some general idea to try first. Or, post what you have and we'll look. :)

Comment: This is the code I am using:

function swapSphere(){
 var $active = $('#image .active');
 var $next = ($('#image .active').next().length>0) ? $('#image .active').next() : $('#image img:first');
 
 $active.fadeOut(function(){
  $active.removeClass('active');
  $next.fadeIn().addClass('active');
 });
}